# Weird include problem. Unknown override specifier

Tags: c++

I have 3 classes (Object, Component, Transform)and one Namespace(Engine).
Engine Namespace:

```
#pragma once

namespace Engine {

#include <GLM/glm.hpp>

#include "../Objects/Object.h"
#include "../Objects/Components/Component.h"
#include "../Objects/Components/Transform.h"

}
```

Object class:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <GLM/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

#include "../Rendering/Loader.h"

#include "../Namespaces/Engine.h"

class Object {

public:
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 rotation;
    glm::vec3 scale;

    Object();
    Object(glm::vec3 position, glm::vec3 rotation, glm::vec3 scale);
};
```

Component class:

```
#pragma once

class Component {

public:
    unsigned int id;

};
```

Transform class:

```
#pragma once

#include "../../Namespaces/Engine.h"

using namespace Engine;

class Transform : public Component {

public:
    Object object; <-- unknown override specifier

    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 rotation;
    glm::vec3 scale;

};
```

I know that the problem is because Engine.h is included in Object.h and Object.h is included in Engine.h so that Object variable in Transform doesn't know it exists, but why, and how do I fix it without removing the Object include from Engine.h since I need to make Object and other Components easily accessible with just including Engine.h. I know that this is a compiler error but is there some sort of way to fix it without including the Object.h separetely in other files ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow why you need to include `Engine.h` before your `Object` class efinition.

Comment: Include cycle: transform.h <-> engine.h

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, always include a full and complete copy-paste (as text) of the errors you get.

Comment: I guess the answer depends on what your project actually wants to accomplish. There are many ways to break a cycle in a graph; which one is best, only you can know.

Comment: That first `namespace` with the `#include` directives inside of it looks very suspicious and quite wrong.

Comment: @Eljay it just because i wanted to have namespace that someone can just use and it will contain the classes, I get the same error if i don't use the Engine namespace at all and just use the Engine.h file

Comment: @ChrisHusky It is not the proper way to use a namespace. And it is not a good practice to use namespaces from header (as it can bring back potential name conflicts for which purpose namespace were added to the langage).

Comment: You need to learn about **forward declarations** (for ex. `class Object; `). If the classe is defined in a namespace, the forward declaration must be also declared inside the same namespace as the real declaration. **Short answer**: You cannot have mutually recursive included.  **Other recommendation**: avoid global header like `Engine.h` that try to included everything.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR avoid circular `#include` directives like the plague.

Remember, the preprocessor just does text replacement.  When it encounters an `#include` directive it literally replaces that directive with the (preprocessed) text of the included file.

In this case, the actual result will vary depending on exactly which header you include.  Your error will occur any time you try to directly include Object.h.

With that in mind, let's take the role of the preprocessor to see what the problem is.  Lets start preprocessing Object.h:

```cpp
#pragma once
```

We've encountered our first directive.  This tells us to make a note that we've already included this file in this compilation unit and skip it if we're told to include it again.  We won't generate any output for this directive.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <GLM/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

#include "../Rendering/Loader.h"
```

Our next directives.  We've been asked to include the contents a couple of other headers.  I'm going to skip over these in this answer since they aren't relevant to the problem.

```cpp
// contents of iostream
// contents of GLM/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp

// contents of Loader.h

#include "../Namespaces/Engine.h"
```

We've been asked to include the contents of Engine.h.  To do so, we'll need to preprocess it first.

```cpp
#pragma once

namespace Engine {

#include <GLM/glm.hpp>
```

Same as before, nothing too interesting here.  Do note that including GLM/glm.hpp into the `Engine` namespace will likely cause compiler/linker errors later in the toolchain.  We're just a preprocessor though, so we don't care about any of that.

```cpp
namespace Engine {

// contents of GLM/glm.hpp

#include "../Objects/Object.h"
```

Another include directive.  We were told using `#pragma once` to skip over future includes of Object.h though, so we won't produce any output for this directive.

```cpp
namespace Engine {

// contents of GLM/glm.hpp

#include "../Objects/Components/Component.h"
```

This one's pretty simple, we'll just preprocess and include Component.h.

```cpp
namespace Engine {

// contents of GLM/glm.hpp

class Component {

public:
    unsigned int id;

};
#include "../Objects/Components/Transform.h"
```

Another include directive.  Lets start preprocessing Transform.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "../../Namespaces/Engine.h"
```

We've been asked to include Engine.h, but we were already told by a `#pragma once` to skip future includes of that file, so we won't produce any output for this.  That means that the entire preprocessed Transform.h will look like this:

```cpp
using namespace Engine;

class Transform : public Component {

public:
    Object object;

    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 rotation;
    glm::vec3 scale;

};
```

Now that we're finished with Transform.h, we can jump back up a level and paste that into Engine.h

```cpp
namespace Engine {

// contents of GLM/glm.hpp

class Component {

public:
    unsigned int id;

};

using namespace Engine;

class Transform : public Component {

public:
    Object object;

    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 rotation;
    glm::vec3 scale;

};

}
```

And that's the end of Engine.h, so we can jump back up a level and paste that into Object.h.  There aren't any further preprocessor directives in Object.h, so the preprocessor result for that file will look like this

```cpp
// contents of iostream
// contents of GLM/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp

// contents of Loader.h

namespace Engine {

// contents of GLM/glm.hpp

class Component {

public:
    unsigned int id;

};

using namespace Engine;

class Transform : public Component {

public:
    Object object;

    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 rotation;
    glm::vec3 scale;

};

}

class Object {

public:
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 rotation;
    glm::vec3 scale;

    Object();
    Object(glm::vec3 position, glm::vec3 rotation, glm::vec3 scale);
};
```

Now you may be able to spot the problem.  The `Object` class is referenced in `Transform` before it's defined.  Note that it's also not defined to be in the `Engine` namespace like you likely expect it to be.

---

The way to solve this problem is to make sure your include graph has no cycles.  If you want a big meta-header that users can include to get all of your library's functionality that's fine, but nothing within your library should include that header.  You also shouldn't wrap your headers in a namespace externally.  That will never work.  Also note that `#pragma once` has problems, and the standard `#ifndef`/`#define` include guards tend to be more robust.  `#pragma once` is OK, but IMO its best to avoid it.  You should also sort out your project's include paths so that you don't need to use relative paths.

All of that said, something more like this will do the trick.  It will allow consumers of this library to simply `#include <Engine.h>` to get everything or include individual headers to only get the pieces they want:

Object.h

```cpp
#ifndef MYLIB_OBJECT_H
#define MYLIB_OBJECT_H

#include "MyLib/Rendering/Loader.h"

#include <GLM/glm.hpp>
#include <GLM/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace Engine {

class Object {

public:
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 rotation;
    glm::vec3 scale;

    Object();
    Object(glm::vec3 position, glm::vec3 rotation, glm::vec3 scale);
};

}

#endif
```

Component.h

```cpp
#ifndef MYLIB_COMPONENT_H
#define MYLIB_COMPONENT_H

namespace Engine {

class Component {

public:
    unsigned int id;

};

}

#endif
```

Transform.h

```cpp
#ifndef MYLIB_TRANSFORM_H
#define MYLIB_TRANSFORM_H

#include "MyLib/Object/Object.h"
#include "MyLib/Object/Components/Component.h"

#include <GLM/glm.hpp>

namespace Engine {

class Transform : public Component {

public:
    Object object;

    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 rotation;
    glm::vec3 scale;

};

}

#endif
```

Engine.h

```cpp
// Note, #include <GLM/glm.hpp> has been moved to individual headers

#include "MyLib/Objects/Object.h"
#include "MyLib/Objects/Components/Component.h"
#include "MyLib/Objects/Components/Transform.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to include using namespace in your Engine header so the using keyword passed down multiple times, your transformer header doesn't recognize Engine::Object. get rid of the using namespace line and it will work

Comment: I tried to remove the "using namespace Engine" line in Transform.h and it throws out the same error, I even found out that class Object was for some reason not in the Engine namespace and when I modified the class a bit then it was part of the namespace but now i have extra error in Transform.h saying that Object is not part of Engine namespace even when it is

Comment: it says that Object isn't part of Engine namespace

Answer (score -3):

I'm not that experienced in C++ but it seems to me that one should use `#define`, `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`.

Example:

A.h

```
#ifndef A_h
#define A_h
#include "B.h"
class A
{
public:
    void func(B *param);
};
#endif // A_h
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B_h
#define B_h
 
#include "A.h"
class B
{
public:
    void func(A *param);
};
#endif // B_h
```

Comment: Nope, that's not it. OP achieves the exact same effect using `#pragma once`. While it's not a part of the standard C++, all modern compilers support `#pragma once`.

Comment: This still has a circular dependency. Rather than `#include "B.h"`, you should simply forward declare `class B;` and do the same for `A`.

Comment: I use Visual studio 2019 and there #pragma once does the same thing but this only works in some IDE's, like this doesn't work in Code::Blocks I think

Comment: @ChrisHusky CB uses GCC as the compiler by default, and `#pragma once` does work on GCC.